# Importing CSV into Excel via Data -> From Text/CSV: Can I automatically apply the Power Query column formats?

Tags: microsoft-excel, csv, power-query

Microsoft® Excel® for Microsoft 365 MSO (Version 2402 Build 16.0.17328.20124) 64-bit

I have an external program that creates CSVs.  Some of the columns have eg. $ or %. The import query is smart enough to automatically format these columns.

From the advanced query editor (excerpt):

```
{"NetProfit", Currency.Type}, {"ROR", Percentage.Type}, {"RAR", Percentage.Type}, {"MaxDD", Percentage.Type}, {"AvgDD", Percentage.Type},
```

In the Power Query window, the percentage columns have "%" in the column header name and XX% in the column data. The currency columns have "$" in the column header name, but no "$" in the column data.

However, once I Close & Load, the columns in Excel are unformatted: everything is "General" format, and in particular the percentage columns are rather unreadable.

Is there a way to coax Excel to actually *USE* the column formatting that the Power Query editor was so diligent in applying?

I have many CSVs imported into this single Excel workbook, and it is a pain to have to manually format each column to match the formatting that the Power Query created.

Comment: As far I know, when imported to excel will show as `General`. You need to format the cells, Once formatted the cell manually goto `Table Design` --> `Properties` --> Check `Preserve cell formatting`. This will preserve the formatting every time there is refresh in the imported table

Comment: Not relevant to your problem, but be aware that the `$` and `%` symbols you see in the column header are a representation of the data type and not a part of the **`Name`**

Comment: Ok thanks all.  Bummer that Excel doesn't propagate the power query column type to Excel, or at least allow this as a choice.  Seems like this would be an obvious design decision.